# Can't get text from another class to print out on another one (noob)

Tags: java, getter, getter-setter

I posted this code earlier, and I got alot of helpful answers and the majority was that I need to change my code completely. Which I understand, and I will do tomorrow! But right now, this is eating away at me at why this won't work.

I am trying to get the sendText from the ChatBox class, to my MessageWindow class and output in the messagePane. That's it. It seems so simple, and it probably is...but I have literally been at this for 10 hours straight. I just want it to output what I put in the ChatBox to the MessageWindow, without completely changing my code. Please help :(

```
public class ChatBox extends JPanel {

private JScrollPane scrollPane;
private String sendText;

public ChatBox() {
    final JTextArea chatPane = new JTextArea();

    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(chatPane,
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    add(scrollPane);
    scrollPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(550, 50));
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550, 50));

    chatPane.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if( e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER ) {
                sendText = chatPane.getText();
                setText(sendText);
                chatPane.setText(null);
                // System.out.println(sendText); // I can see this in console
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        }

    });

}


public String getText() {
    return sendText;
}


public void setText(String sendText) {
    this.sendText = sendText;
}
```

}

In my head, I am setting the sendText -> whatever I input. Then in the MessageWindow class, I am trying to use the getter to get the text and output in the messagePane.

```
public class MessageWindow extends JPanel {

private ChatBox box = new ChatBox();

public MessageWindow() {
    JTextArea messagePane = new JTextArea();

    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

    gc.weightx = 1;
    gc.weighty = 1;
    gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    add(new JScrollPane(messagePane), gc);

    System.out.println(box.getText());   // Getting null in the console.
    messagePane.append(box.getText());   // Not getting anything on messagePane.

}
```

}

I know I need to use ActionListeners and a JTextField, instead of a JTextArea. And I promise I will start that tomorrow. I will scrap this whole program as it is, I just need to know why this basic things fails me :( I knew while I was learning Java that getters/setters were going to be a problem for me to completely understand, and I guess I am right about that lol...

Thanks for any help!!!

**NEW CODE**

```
public class MessageWindow extends JPanel {

private ChatBox box = new ChatBox(this);

public void OnTextSet(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
}

public MessageWindow() {
    JTextArea messagePane = new JTextArea();

    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

    gc.weightx = 1;
    gc.weighty = 1;
    gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    add(new JScrollPane(messagePane), gc);

    System.out.println(box.getText()); // Getting null in the console.
    messagePane.append(box.getText()); // Not getting anything on
                                        // messagePane.

}
```

}

And

```
public class ChatBox extends JPanel {

private JScrollPane scrollPane;
private String sendText = "";
private MessageWindow mw;

public ChatBox() {
    final JTextArea chatPane = new JTextArea();

    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(chatPane,
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    add(scrollPane);
    scrollPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(550, 50));
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550, 50));

    chatPane.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                sendText = chatPane.getText();
                setText(sendText);
                chatPane.setText(null);
                mw.OnTextSet(sendText);
                // System.out.println(sendText); // I can see this in
                // console
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        }

    });

}

public ChatBox(MessageWindow mw) {
    this.mw = mw;
}


public String getText() {
    return sendText;
}

public void setText(String sendText) {
    this.sendText = sendText;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a link from the `Chatbox` to the `MessageWindow`, inorder to send messages back and forth.

What could be done is modify as below

```
private ChatBox box = new ChatBox(this); //is this legal in java?
                                  ^^^^
public void OnTextSet(String s){
    System.out.println(s);      
}

//elsewhere
private MessageWindow mw;
public ChatBox(MessageWindow mw) {
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   this.mw = mw

...
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
...
   mw.OnTextSet(sendText);
}
```

Now type something and you should see the print out

Comment: I've so given up that I don't even know what I would do to do: "And then use this mw to send your String over." ...Put a fork in me!

Comment: when you say //elsewhere do you mean in the ChatBox class as another class? Or what. That is where I get confused...

Comment: Yes, elsewhere is the the `ChatBox` class. As to send it over, it is as simple as calling a function that takes a string. `mw.sendAString(sendText)`

Comment: Hmm... doesn't seem to be working. It still doesn't return anything :(

Comment: Actually ignore my idea, you seem to have done almost the same thing from the other side

Comment: @Bowhuntr11 try my edited idea, `Chatbox` needs to callback to `MessageWindow` to say the text is ready.

Comment: I posted my new code at the bottom of the top post...Am I missing something? Just getting null in the console and nothing else. Did I put something in the wrong place? This is starting to get over my head, but I do want to just see it work so I can figure it out. Thanks for all your help!!!

Comment: @Bowhuntr11 as I said, you are checking it too soon. Basically you are trying to see if you can check what you typed right? But the check as it currently stands happens before you type :P Hence the `null`. Take a look at my idea for a callback which tries to print after you finish typing

Comment: Sorry yeah, I pasted the same code twice at the bottom. Fixed it now. I am suppose to put that mw.OnTextSet(sendText); in the keyEvent I already created correct? If so it gives a whole new NullPointException error.

Comment: @Bowhuntr11 you have added `this.mw = mw` in its own constructor, one that you are NOT using. Thats the reason. You should add this to the main constructor

Answer (score 0):

The variable *sendText* in ChatBox class isn't initialized on creation. Since *keyReleased* event is not fired yet, *sendText* stays NULL.
Try to modifiy from your code in Chatbox

from:

```
private String sendText;
```

to:

```
private String sendText = "";
```

Comment: Thank you, that did get rid of null at least! Now to figure out how to get that dang sendText to the messagePane! :) Thanks again!

Comment: @Bowhuntr11 your issue is timing, You are trying to check the text before it has been set.. `null` was a correct value :P

Comment: @Bowhuntr11 You should try to put the reading code in a callback which would fire when The Panel is set